# How can I determine a file extension given a file path in LaTeX?

Tags: latex, string, variables, tex

I am attempting to write a LaTeX package which leverages the minted package's \inputminted command. My \mycommand command takes two parameters, the first being a path to a file, and I want to pass the file's extension to the \inputminted command:

```
\newcommand\mycommand[2]{
  \inputminted{#1}{...}
}
```

Note that the above won't work since the full path is passed to \inputminted.

Example:

```
\mycommand{/path/to/Test.java}{blah}
```

should invoke

```
\inputminted{java}{...}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your package use the function \filename@parse

```
\filename@parse{/path/to/Test.java}
```

then you can access the results using

```
\filename@base
\filename@ext
```

So in your case

```
\inputminted{\filename@ext}{...}
```

Comment: No I can't find a reference. I just grepped through my texmf folder and found a package called fink doing something similar. 
Maybe the lack of documentation is related to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2296772/where-can-i-find-help-files-or-documentation-for-commands-like-startsection-for